# How to create a popup in materializecss?

Tags: jquery, css, material-design, aurelia, materialize

Am using Aurelia Js and materializecss in my project, also new to this techs. How to create this kind of popup in materializecss, needs to open on click the vertical doted icon. Cant find a kind of popup in materialcss [material docs](http://materializecss.com/dialogs.html) .

**please find the attachment below**

[image]

Comment: materialize does not include everything you can think of, try "tooltip javascript" as your google query

Comment: or not exactly what you want, but with materialize: http://materializecss.com/dialogs.html#tooltip you can extend the behaviour